# What is "micro-scale" building?

Tags: terminology, micro-scale

I have seen references to "micro-scale" building in LEGO documentation. How is this different than the "normal" LEGO building scale?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It refers to building items at a much smaller scale than the usual "mini-fig" scale.

For example the "Micro" Star Destroyer:

[image]

 [4492 Mini Star Destroyer](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/4492-1)

---

**Edit to add:**

Officially however, when bought as a set they are usually referred to as "Mini-scale".

Answer (score 10):

Microscale is not just a technique, it's an artform:

- [blog explaining it](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621011656/http://62bricks.com:80/micro-scale-lego-building) and a few showcases
- a [very nice example](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=485845)

Comment: A few years ago, there was an official building competition specifically centered around microscale models. The winning entries were made into real LEGO sets.

Comment: LEGO are now bringing out a microscale version of their entire line (so far) of modular Cafe Corner sets